# What are the benefits of having SSAS Cubes over SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, ssas, ssrs-2012

I have a requirement, where i proposed to have the data to be generated in SSRS or export to excel. However, i was told to do SSAS.

What are the benefits of having SSAS Cubes over SSRS?

Apart from performance which includes Aggregate calculation , cache data storing ; What are the benefits or need of having SSAS Cubes over SSRS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using SSRS, you can create a report that does a static evaluation of the source data. You can define specific row and column groups to aggregate the data, and the end-user can export that aggregated result to an Excel file.

Using SSAS, you define a "cube" with multiple (hierarchical) "dimensions" and all kind of useful aggregated values ("measures") from the numbers from the source tables ("facts"). The end-eser can use Excel to connect to the cube and dynamically build a pivot-table using any dimensional level and any measure defined in the cube to build an individual on-demand report for his/her specific need.

While the reports defined with SSRS can access live data, the cube is usually updated based on a schedule, once or multiple times a day (from a "data warehouse").

Comment: Thank you wolfgang, I still have a question. I am doing same data aggregations on my report. Will it be possible to have an example for multiple (hierarchical) "dimensions " as mentioned

Comment: While pivot tables allow the user to specify on what levels of the hierarchies the data should be aggregated, this decision must be made by the report developer of an SSRS report at design-time.

Comment: In addition to Wolfgang's answer, you can also use SSAS as a datasource for SSRS so if you build your data model using SSAS you still have both options available to deliver to end users. 

For users who are comfortable with Pivot tables you can offer them the connection to the SSAS cube via Excel and for those who prefer to just read pre-formatted reports, you can give them a Reporting Services report.

Comment: Thank you @WolfgangKais. Thank you Alan, that description is helpful